# Why doesn't my code insert the values in my database?

Tags: php, insert-into

I'm busy with an assignment of a course and I can't find out what the problem is. The only thing I know is that it's in the insert part. The connection is correct. As I'll show the variables, you can see the words which where put in the input fields. But they are still not in the database.

I used this code before and it worked but I don't see why it doesn't work at this moment. Can anyone please help me? Here below is the code I have.

Thank you for trying to help me!!

```
<?php

// Open connectie naar de database
$link =  mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root'); // maakt de connectie met de databases (mamp/wamp)
if (!$link) {
    die('Geen connectie ' . mysql_error()); // verbreekt de verbinding en laat de error zien
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('voorbeeld', $link); // maakt connectie het database "voorbeeld"
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Kan database niet selecteren : ' . mysql_error());// verbreekt de verbinding en laat de error zien
}

if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Verzenden') {

  $naam = $_POST['naam'];
  $boodschap = $_POST['boodschap'];

  $datum = date("y-m-d");  

  // Bericht opslaan
  $query2 = "INSERT INTO gastenboek (ID, naam, boodschap, datum) 
        VALUES(NULL, '$naam', '$boodschap', '$datum')";
  $result = mysql_query($query2);

  if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
     $success_msg = '<P>Uw bericht is geplaatst.</P>';

  } else {
    error_log(mysql_error());
    $success_msg = '<P>Helaas, er ging iets mis.</P>';
  }

}



$thispage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


<?php
$form_page = <<< EOFORMPAGE
</head>

<body>

<H1>Uw bericht</H1>

$datum
$boodschap
$success_msg

<form method="POST" action="$thispage">

Uw naam:<br/>
<input type="text" SIZE="40" name="naam" value="$naam"><br/><br/>
Uw bericht:<br/>
<textarea name="boodschap" rows=10 cols=50>$boodschap</textarea><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verzenden">
</form>


<a href="gastenboek.php"><input type="button" name="gastenboek" value="Gastenboek"></a>

</body>
</html>

EOFORMPAGE;
echo $form_page;
?>
```

Comment: You are not doing any error checking for your query in your code. It is hence no wonder the code breaks when your query fails. The  [manual on `mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) shows how to do proper error checking. Note that the mysql library is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) and should not be used for new code.

Comment: Please, seriously stop coding guestbooks until you really know what you are doing and don't skip the security chapter in your php book.

Comment: Side note: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You need to use the appropriate method of your database library to escape your data prior to making the query.

Comment: Does `ID` really allow null?  If it has a default value, maybe just leave `ID` and `NULL` out.

Comment: To Mike Christensen, you are right. That whas the problem. Thank you.

Of course also to Pekka thank you for sending the link! It helped me!

Comment: @Hanneke - Glad it worked, I've posted it as an answer as well..

Answer (score 2):

*(From my comment)*

It looks like you're trying to insert *NULL* into an ID field.  If that column uses a default value or a seed/incrementing value, you can just omit it:

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO gastenboek (naam, boodschap, datum) 
           VALUES('$naam', '$boodschap', '$datum')";
```

**Also**, even though it's just a homework assignment, it's a good idea to get familiar with **security vulnerabilities** exposed by not [sanitizing user input](http://xkcd.com/327/).  I'd get familiar with this:

http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

Remove NULL from ID because it may be your primary key or you may have applied autoincrement to it.